# What is the best open source credential manager?

Tags: open-source, password-manager

I am looking for an open source / free software password & credentials management tool, capable of isolation for various teams, able to store human passwords but also managing crypto keys for servers, ideally with SCIM provisioning. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Did you take a look at [Bitwarden](https://bitwarden.com/)? It seems to match all your requirements listed here:

- it is [open source](https://bitwarden.com/open-source/)
- it can isolate [teams](https://bitwarden.com/learning/getting-started-as-a-teams-administrator/)
- of course it can store "human passwords", also any sort of keys
- it supports [SCIM provisioning](https://bitwarden.com/help/about-scim/)